# Why does the compiler convert bool to integer and back to bool instead of returning the bool itself?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, aforge

I was reading `VideoFileWriter` class from `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` assembly via ILSPY (I was interested to see how a particular method works) and found this:

```
public bool IsOpen {
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    get {
        return ((this.data != null) ? 1 : 0) != 0;
    }
}
```

What's the reason to do that bool to integer than back to bool conversion rather just do `this.data != null`?

Comment: Try compare with JustDecompile

Comment: Or try with DotPeek

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is decompiled code, it is likely just a glitch of the decompiler.

---

After thinking for a bit, here is a reasonable implementation that may potentially turn in to the same compiled code

```
public enum ConnectionState
{
    Closed = 0,
    Open = 1,
    Opening = 2,
    OtherStuff = 3,
    AndSoOn = 4,
}

public bool IsOpen
{
    get
    {
        ConnectionState state;
        if (this.data != null)
        {
            state = ConnectionState.Open;
        }
        else
        {
            state = ConnectionState.Closed;
        }

        return state != ConnectionState.Closed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I tried other decompilers and got different outputs, like that ` public bool IsOpen
        {
            get
            {
                object obj;
                if (this.data != null)
                {
                    obj = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    obj = null;
                }
                return (byte)obj;
            }
        }`